# Programmatically uninstall iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone application, I wanna show term and condition of my company to user and ask user to agree or not if first time application load. If user doesn't agree, I want to uninstall my application from user's iphone. Is it possible?

Comment: i think you like to go for the in app purchase! i may wright

Comment: Isn't downloading the app from the app store implied acceptance of the terms anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this from the API.  The best you can do is lock down your application if the user doesn't agree to your terms.

Comment: how to lock down application?

Comment: If they don't accept your terms, then write your code so that the app doesn't allow them to do anything.

Answer (score 6):

No but you can prevent the user going any farther into your app unless they accept the terms.

They will manually uninstall if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Why will you like to do that ?
I will suggest that your application should not proceed ahead and keep on giving the dialog of acceptance. So user will not be able to use your application till he/she says yes. Let the user install/unistall the app if he/she wishes. This also gives your application the opportunity of getting accepted by user at some point of time in the future.

Comment: ok.But I want to go to user iPhone's home if user donesn't agree with my terms.Is it also possible?

Comment: These kind of activities are discouraged as such by Apple and your app may fall in rejected category if you do so. Read Human interface guidline (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)

Answer (score 1):

hm, I think apple had an ToS for the applications that appears on the app store. Then, Why would you like to do that..?

I think all you have to do is create an splash view/screen for the first time the app launch to show to the user about your company rather than trying to create an uninstall script.